Differences between dotnet build -r and dotnet publish -r
With the following project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

Here is my undestanding of the situation:
When I build without any runtime specified (dotnet build), it generates the binaries into bin\release\net8.0-windows where I have a runtimes folder that contains all the runtime specific dependencies. When I run my application from this location, it works because it determines which runtime we are on and select the appropriate dependencies into the runtimes folder.
When I build with a specified runtime (dotnet build -r win-x64 for example), the binaries are generated into bin\release\net8.0-windows\win-x64, without any runtimes folder because it is runtime dependent. When I run my application from this location, it works only if I am on a windows with the x64 runtime installed.
When I publish with the same runtime (dotnet publish -r win-x64 for example), the binaries are generated into bin\release\net8.0-windows\win-x64\publish, with an extra web.config file. Same as the previous case, it can run only in a win-x64 environment.
I thought the publish target was generating a runtime dependent package by keeping the good dependencies within the runtimes folder and getting rid of the other. But according to this question (Why do I have to specify the runtime identifier in the csproj for a publish?), the publish needs some other prerequistes to work properly.
So what are the differences between dotnet build -r win-x64 and dotnet publish -r win-x64? This extra web.config file isn't even necessary to run the application on the right environment.

Publish create a setup.exe file like commercial software that you use to install on a deploy machine.  Publish adds windows dlls to the setup folder as well as the runtime version of core.
